# Why can one not daven to change the gender of a fetus?

Tags: tefilla, tractate-brachot, bava-metzia

According to [Bava Metzia 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.42a.5), one may daven for things in the past if it's something that nobody knows yet.

Yet, when [Berachos 60a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60a.14) asks how one may daven to change the gender of her fetus on the grounds that its gender is determined from the moment of fertilization, it answers that the fertilization took place in such a way that leaves its gender unresolved until morphogenesis begins after forty days.

Why does the Gemara in Berachos not answer that we're dealing with a regular fertilization, and one may daven to change the gender of the fetus because its gender isn't recognizable until after forty days?

Comment: This question (more or less) is asked in Daf Al Hadaf on the Gemara in Bava Metzia.

Comment: How does one recognize the gender after forty days?

Comment: @Alex I'm not aware of that source

Comment: @robev I'm not entirely sure, but my understanding is as I presented it here, that morphogenesis, i.e. the beginning of forming the fetus into the shape of a human being begins around forty days.

Comment: @DonielF https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48180&st=&pgnum=161

Comment: @Alex You're right, fundamentally he seems to be asking the same question, though he phrases it the other way around – based on Berachos saying that you can't daven for a miracle, how can BM say you can daven on something hidden? I don't fully understand his answer, though; if you think you do, feel free to write it up.

Comment: @DonielF I don't really understand the answer either. Even if the request is only that God's promise should occur in this particular stash of grain, it would still require the same miracle to change what's already there.

Answer (score -1):

If the gender is unrecognizable, but determined within the first 40 days, then it does not matter what he davens for because it has been fixed. The gemara *brachos 60a* (ArtScroll 60a3) explains that once something has been determined, even if the person does not know it, one cannot daven for the change. Note also the example of the house on fire. In the example in Bava Metzia, the amount of grain is not necessarily fixed as Hashem can cause it to increase without an obvious miracle as one can assume that that was the amount of grain present from the first. That is why the gemara gives a different bracha before he begins to count it and in the middle of counting it. In the case of a infant, since the normal determination is even in the first 40 days, one cannot **normally** pray. Art Scroll on that daf note 24 points to *Avudraham* in his explanation of the weekday morning service. If a person is aware of the sign that specifies the future sex, then it is improper to pray for a neis.

Art Scroll Brachos 60a3 note 25:

> [Since one cannot be certain who emitted seed first,] one can always
>   pray for a particular gender within 40 days (*Tur, Orach Chaim 230*)
>   for perhaps they emitted their seed at the same time (*Pri Megadim* to
>   *Magen Avraham 230:1*; see also *Sifsei Chachamim* in explanation of *Rashi*).

Comment: "the amount of grain is not necessarily fixed as Hashem can cause it to increase without a miracle" What??

Comment: @DoubleAA Without an obvious miracle as one can assume that that was the amount of grain present from the first. I will add this to the post. This is what we learned in the daf yomi shiur.

Comment: One can also assume that was the gender that was there originally

Comment: @DoubleAA That is why the note states that one can pray assuming that both had emitted seed together. The gemara is stating that if one knew which had emitted seed first, then one has already seen the sign as to which gender will occur. It would be like seeing that the amount of grain does not completely fill a bin of known capacity. In that case it gives a maximum possible volume.